# Replace the elements in a list by different variables, prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list like

```
['_', '_', '#', '_']
```

Is there any way I can let system generate some different variables and replace each '_' with one of the variables?
Thanks

Comment: Yes. But can you specify how you want your predicate to be called?

Comment: Someone asked exactly this question a few days ago but I don't see it in the recent history, so probably this is for the same class and your peer deleted the question after it was answered.

Comment: @lurker hmm.. like convert([T|Ts], [A|As]) :- (T == '_' -> .... ; ...). Do you mean this?

Comment: @DanielLyons Ah.. Really? I was trying to solve it by myself, but I tried a lot and searched a lot, still not success...

Comment: A lot of students try that in the Prolog tag. When it happens to me, I usually arrange for a moderator to undelete the question, but if I'm not an answerer I usually don't remember enough to reconstruct the deleted question's URL. Perhaps others with more authority than I have can.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my replace/2 program always return false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459971/why-does-my-replace-2-program-always-return-false)

Comment: @jacobbb not exactly. That's part of a declaration. I was looking for how you wanted to run the query.

Comment: @lurker That seems a same question with mine, Thanks

Comment: And now you have more answers to pick from. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple implementation:

```
var('_', _):- !.
var(X, X).
```

Example run:

```
?- maplist(var, ['_','_','#','_'], L).
L = [_G313, _G316, #, _G322].
```

The cut (exclamation mark) is used to leave out any choicepoints. (Try leaving the cut out, you will see that you will get an idle choicepoint by pressing semicolon.)